# How can I move the Y-Axis labels from the bottom to the top of my horizontal bar rad chart?

Tags: silverlight, telerik, radchart

By default, the Y-Axis labels appear on the bottom of a horizontal bar chart. How can I display them on the top instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have only one Y-Axis, it will be placed under the "YAxis" placeholder, which is the bottom.
You need to create an empty Y-Axis beforehand. This way, the "good" Y-Axis will be placed under the "YAxis2" placeholder, which is the top.

Note that those locations are specific for the horizontal bar chart. You can check this [example](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/chart-axes.html) for column chart.